# How to link Google Play Services to cordova project

Tags: cordova, google-play-services, android-appcompat

I want to ask what is the correct way to link Google Play Services and, v7 Support libraries to Cordova Project without using `Eclipse` i tried two ways both didn't work.

I brought the folder google-play-services_lib from

`${android sdk}\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib`

To

`the root of my cordova project under platofoms/android`

I also brought the folder appcompat from

`${androidsdk}\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat`

To

```
the root of my cordova project under platforms/android
```

and change my `project.properties` file under  platforms/android to this:

```
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
# Project target.
target=android-19
android.library.reference.2=google-play-services_lib
android.library.reference.3=appcompat
```

But didn't work.

I've also did something stupid and linked them directly from the android SDK located in my c:/ drive but i got also an error:

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:577: Failed to resolve library path: C:adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030sdkextrasgooglegoogle_play_serviceslibprojectgoogle-play-services_lib
```